# retrieve date from oracle c++

Tags: c++, oracle

Hello i am trying to get information from table,

```
CREATE TABLE Locks (
lid CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
bno CHAR(3),
rno CHAR(4),
status VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (bno, rno) REFERENCES Labs
```

);

this my table, i am trying to get lid 
but when i execute the query it does not return id
But when i try to find the bno or rno it does return them 
here is my code

```
struct STMT {
string name;
Statement *stmt;};


initStatements(Connection *conn, STMT * & statements){
int size = 1;
statements = new STMT[size];
statements[0].name = "Checklid";
string queryStr = "select * from Locks where lid = :1";
statements[0].stmt = conn->createStatement(queryStr);

return size;
}

Statement * findStatement(string name, STMT *statements, int size){
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (statements[i].name == name)
        return statements[i].stmt;
}
return 0;
  } 

void checkforcid(STMT *statements, int size){
Statement *stmt;
 stmt = findStatement("Checklid", statements, size);

 string Clid;
cout << "Please enter lid: ";
cin >> Clid;

stmt->setString(1, Clid);
ResultSet *rs = stmt->executeQuery();
 int i = 0;
while (rs->next()) {
      string lid = rs->getString(1);
    cout << "lid : " << lid << endl;
      i++;
}
 //cout << i << endl;
stmt->closeResultSet(rs);
}

int main()
{
string userName = "alsaiama";
string password;
const string connectString = "";


cout << "Your user name: ";
getline(cin, userName);

cout << "Your password: ";
password = readPassword();
cout << endl;

Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment();
Connection *conn = env->createConnection
                      (userName, password, connectString);

STMT *statements;
int size = initStatements(conn, statements);


 checkforcid(statements,size);



terminateStatements(conn, statements, size);
env->terminateConnection(conn);
Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem lid should be 10 long in the database (CHAR(10))